# MapBox iOS SDK: add map event

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to setup an iOS app with the latest MapBox iOS idk (3.2). How much i seek the internet, I can't find an example how to add a map event to the mapview.

For example: i want to add an event when the map becomes idle. Any suggestions?

UPDATE

I think this is the right method to implement:

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {


}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you’re asking how to use delegate methods, here’s how:

```
import Mapbox

// Declare conformance to the MGLMapViewDelegate protocol
class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

    var mapView: MGLMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        // Set the delegate property of our map view to self after instantiating it.
        mapView.delegate = self
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) -> Bool {
        // look at mapView properties and do something
    }
}
```

See https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/ for examples of how to implement basic features with the Mapbox iOS SDK.